# Access to the path 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\IIS Express\\Excel.xlsx' is denied

Tags: c#, asp.net, excel, iis

I'm working on a ASP.NET MVC 5 project. In this project I want user to download an Excel file using this code :

```
var workbook = new ExcelFile();
    workbook.Save("Excel.xlsx");
```

But when I enter the URL to download the Excel file. I get the exception :

> Access to the path 'C:\Program Files (x86)\IIS Express\Excel.xlsx'
>   is denied.

How can I modify my code so that user can download the Excel file wherever he wants? Instead of IIS Express folder. Thanks.

Comment: You need to modify the permissions on that folder and not your code.

Comment: If the Excel file is created when the user is wanting it downloaded, don't bother saving it. Just create a temp file, send out to the user, then close the file. No need for permissions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my opinion you have two options.

**1:** Chage the permission of the IIS folder/directory.

**2:** Save the file to Response an let the user choose per SaveFileDialog(try this: [Downloading Excel File](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28066181/downloading-excel-file))

Answer (score 1):

I know its too late, but in order to access the folder you should run visual studio as admin.